# When flipping coins, what is the probability that you'll repeat yourself completely at some point?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, stochastic-processes

You play the following game: you flip a coin over and over again and write down the sequence of Heads (H) and Tails (T). The game ends when you repeat the whole sequence from the beginning. So for example HH or HTHHHTHH would terminate. What is the probability that the game is finite?

It has to be bigger than 50% since this is the probability of starting with HH or TT, ending the game instantly. But the longer the game goes, the less likely it becomes that it ends at all.

I ran the game a few times with the computer and it seems that a probability of 75% may be the answer.

Comment: This is [A122536](https://oeis.org/A122536).  I note that it is conjectured that the number of non-"repeating" strings of length $n$ is asymptotically $C\times 2^n$ for $C\sim .27004$ which seems to be in line with your data, but it doesn't look as if the problem is resolved.

Comment: See also https://www.semanticscholar.org/reader/462ed0f46c9eef74b3873c7c590f8dd4784d5c07 where the conjecture above is proved

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in the comments, the correct asympototic seems to be around $73\%$, but the problem is quite hard, [see for example](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.03689).

A quick and dirty approximation, among many: let $A_k$ denote the event that the first $k$ elements in the sequence ($X_1, X_2 \cdots X_k$) are identical to the next $k$ elements ($X_{k+1}, X_{k+2} \cdots X_{2k}$). Let $B_k$ be its complement event.

It can be show that, for $j\ne k$, the events  $A_k,A_j$ are independent. But that independence is only pairwise, it does not extend to more events. For example $P(A_k \wedge A_{k-1})=P(A_k) P(A_{k-1})$ but $P(A_k \wedge A_{k-1} \wedge A_{k-2}) = P(A_k \wedge A_{k-1}) \ne P(A_k) P(A_{k-1})P(A_{k-2})$. The same, of course, applies to $B_k$.

We are interested in the limit as $n \to \infty$ of
$$\begin{align}p_n&=P(B_1 \wedge B_2 \cdots \wedge B_
n) \\&= P(B_1) P(B_2|B_1) P(B_3|B_1,B_2) \cdots P(B_n|B_{n-1}\cdots  B_1) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

If we assume independence is a fair approximation, then $P(B_n|B_{n-1}\cdots  B_1) \approx P(B_n)$ and

$$\begin{align}p_n &\approx \prod_{k=1}^n P(B_k) = \prod_{k=1}^n (1- (1/2)^{k}) \end{align}$$

In the limit, this is the [Euler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_function), and

$$p_\infty = 0.288788\cdots $$

This is not far from the true value ($0.270043395258\cdots)$. Sadly, I don't see how to improve it or have some bounds. If we can assert that
$P(B_n|B_{n-1}\cdots  B_1) \le  P(B_n)$ (which seems true, but does not seem easy to prove), then we could conclude that the value above is an upper bound. For what's worth, the first correct terms in $(1)$ are

$$\left(1- \frac12\right)
\left(1- \frac14\right)
\left(1- \frac18- \frac{1}{24}\right)
\left(1- \frac1{16} -\frac{1}{80}\right)
\left(1- \frac1{32} -\frac{3}{1184}\right)
\left(1- \frac1{64} -\frac{17}{9152}\right)
\cdots
$$